# run specific command without sudo inside script running with sudo bash

Tags: git, bash, shell, ubuntu, sudo

I have a `bash` script which I'm running with `sudo`: `sudo NewScript`

Inside the script, I have a `git` command which I don't want to run with `sudo`. Currently, since the entire script is run with `sudo` this command also runs with `sudo` and that's what I would like to suppress.

Is such thing possible or do I need to run the script without `sudo` and add `sudo` for every command inside the script other than the `git` command?

Comment: When you run a script with `sudo`, the script is run basically as if it was run by the root user. So the only solution I can think of is to run your git command with permissions of a specific user like so: `sudo -S [username] [git command]`

Comment: If the latter approach, if `sudo` required a password, you will be prompted for password for all such commands.

Answer (score 11):

Note that `sudo` runs programs as a *different* user, not necessarily as `root`; `root` is just the default. So your goal is probably not to run your specific `git` command without `sudo`, but rather to run it as a different user than the rest.

If you want you git command to be run by a hard-coded user `the_user`, just put

```
sudo -u the_user <your git command>
```

in your script (this will not prompt you for your password when the script is run as root).

If you don't know the user in advance but rather want the `git` command to be run by whoever called `sudo newScript` use

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER <your git command>
```

instead (thanks to @thatotherguy for that hint).

Answer (score 4):

One approach to use is switch to normal user privileges using `su` and run it dynamically than actually changing the access.

Run the `git` commands with the normal `$USER` privileges inside the script.

```
su - "$USER" -c "git_command1; git_command2;"
```

The `-c` flag for passing commands to the shell, according to `man su` page,

> -c, --command=command
>               Pass command to the shell with the -c option.